# Why do I get a missing column error on login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm running spree version 4.0.2 on Rails 6.0.2.1 and I've encountered the following error when I try to login or logout:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column spree_orders.guest_token does not exist
LINE 1: ...t" IS NULL AND "spree_orders"."currency" = $1 AND "spree_ord...
                                                             ^
):
    10:   <ul class="nav navbar-right" data-hook>
    11:     <li id="link-to-cart" class="nav-item" data-hook>
    12:       <noscript>
    13:         <%= link_to_cart %>
    14:       </noscript>
    15:        
    16:     </li>
```

I know that the problem is that a query is being generated somewhere when link-to-cart is executed that refers to the column column guest_token which was changed to token in a migration. My Gemfile is shown below.

Can anyone help me with this? I'm relatively new to ruby, rails, and spree, so if I've left out important information, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Jeff

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'spree', '~> 4.0'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 4.0'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.6'
gem 'aws-sdk-s3', require: false
#gem "google-cloud-storage", "~> 1.11", require: false
gem 'spree_braintree_vzero', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_braintree_vzero'
gem 'spree_i18n', :github => 'spree/spree_i18n'
gem 'spree_globalize', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_globalize'
gem 'activerecord-nulldb-adapter'
```

Comment: You changed the attribute, are you asking for the old token?  Find out where that query is coming from and change that query to ask for token.

Answer (score 1):

For me it seemed to be `spree_braintree_vzero` gem.
Maybe it doesn't work with the latest Spree v4 ?

### How to Uninstall and Remove Spree Braintree VZero

It may be useful to see what the install script is doing here:

https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_braintree_vzero/blob/master/lib/generators/spree_braintree_vzero/install/install_generator.rb

To uninstall `spree_braintree_vzero` I had to do the following.

### Remove the Gem from `Gemfile`

```
gem 'spree_braintree_vzero', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_braintree_vzero'
```

### Remove `all.js` changes

`vendor/assets/javascripts/spree/backend/all.js (git)`

```
//= require spree/backend/spree_braintree_vzero
```

`vendor/assets/javascripts/spree/frontend/all.js`

```
//= require spree/frontend/spree_braintree_vzero
```

### Delete `config/schedule.rb`

Yep that is all. Unless it existed before you ran the installer.
You can remove it if all it has in it is `rake 'spree_braintree_vzero:update_states'`, otherwise remove that line from it and the surrounding blocks.

Example: https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_braintree_vzero/blob/1bc400bb598bf177edfe614aef44fcd28eca2312/lib/generators/spree_braintree_vzero/install/install_generator.rb#L15

### Add Migrations to Revert Migrations

**Note**: These could change so check your logs for what you did when you added it.
PS: Don't worry about migrations that touched on the `spree_braintree_checkout` table since it's going to be dropped.

Protip: don't forget to run your migrations ;)

```rb
class DropSpreeBraintreeCheckouts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up
    drop_table :spree_braintree_checkouts
  end

  def down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

```rb
class RemoveBraintreeIdFromSpreeAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    remove_column :spree_addresses, :braintree_id
  end
end
```

```rb
class RemoveBraintreeTokenAndNonceFromSpreePayments < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    remove_column :spree_payments, :braintree_token
    remove_column :spree_payments, :braintree_nonce
  end
end
```